# enhancing a rails gem/plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, acts-as-tree

I want to enhance the functionality of acts-as-taggable-on by adding parent_id and acts_as_tree to the tag model.
how do i edit the gem/plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Github page and fork the application. Make your changes and commit them . Simple.